# How to sort in laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When i sort it gives me data like this:

```
10
19
100
20
abc
fff
```

How can i properly sort it like this:

```
10
19
20
100
abc
fff

Model::orderBy('text','asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

The **[sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby)** method sorts the collection by the given key. The sorted collection keeps the original array keys :

```
$q = Model::orderBy('text','asc')->get();
$sorted = $q->sortBy('text');
```

Alternatively, you can use **[sortByDesc()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortbydesc)** method. `sortDesc()`
method will sort the collection in the opposite order as the `sort()` method.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare the field in your table as an Integer and not as a String.
If a field is of String type its values are evaluated like this:
"100" < "20"
But if the field is of Integer type, eloquent evaluate like this:
20 < 100
Hi.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sortBy to sort your data with passing closer to your query, have added an example you can use it.

```
class::all()->sortBy(function ($query){
   return $query->Your_Field_Name;
});
```

It will also depend on what data type you have chosen in your migration.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort based on the column if it can be casted to UNSIGNED number, otherwise sort by the column it self:

```
 Model::orderByRaw('CAST(text AS UNSIGNED), text')->get();
```